# How To Add BotDetect CAPTCHA Protection using Thymeleaf on form submission

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, captcha, botdetect

I am implementing **BotDetect CAPTCHA** using the help of this site.

https://captcha.com/doc/java/howto/spring-captcha-integration.html

but I am facing problem because It has implemented using JSP and I am using Thymeleaf. so I am facing problem.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Botdetect Captcha HTML <taglib>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052163/botdetect-captcha-html-taglib)

Comment: yes Slava I got this question also during searching on stackoverflow but I am not getting how should JSP use in Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. can you help me.

Comment: You will not use JSP in Thymeleaf indeed. I didn't implement it myself, but I believe the answer is very clear. Basically, the idea is to use just the main `botdetect` package. You will not include JSP package at all. The main package will generate the captcha image and you will be displaying it with Thymeleaf. When user submits, the verification will be done in your controller. That's all, sounds very straightforward.